# How to calculate the sum of two different fields in a soql query

Tags: bash

I'm making a query in soql to calculate the mean value of two numeric fields H01 and H02 in a json file, whose values are 0.6 and 0.4, respectively. This query gets a single record. The query is like this:

```
query="SELECT H01,H02, $((H01 + H02))/2 AS AVERAGE WHERE pollutant = 'H6' AND DATA = '2020-05-08T00:00:00.000' AND location = 'London'"
```

However, when executing this query, the AVERAGE value gives 0, when in fact it is 0.5.

How can I calculate this value and also round the result to 3 decimal places? Thank you.

Comment: I know nothing about `soql` however if you are constructing the query in the shell (as suggested by the `bash` tag), then remember that `$((H01 + H02))` will be expanded by the shell because the query string is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver for your answer. I have done that but it does not work.

Comment: Done what, exactly?

Comment: Sorry @steeldriver, I got confused.